# Print an HTML table of array values and perform basic calculations

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, associative-array

Not sure if this is possible or if I am approaching this the right way but I have been searching around from a couple of hours now with no luck for a solution. I found a couple of examples that I thought would work but none of them have worked in PHP 5.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to print a table of array values (with some calculations)...

My data...

```
$data1 = array('value1'=>'5','value2'=>'7','value3'=>'1');
$data1_sum = array_sum($data1);
$data2 = array('value1'=>'4','value2'=>'1','value3'=>'3');
$data2_sum = array_sum($data2);
```

I would like to print it out in an html table like below and add like values from each array...

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>13</td><!-- Sum of $data1 values -->
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>8</td><!-- Sum of $data2 values -->
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td><!-- Sum of all value1 -->
    <td>8</td><!-- Sum of all value2 -->
    <td>4</td><!-- Sum of all value3 -->
    <td>21</td><!-- Sum of $data1_sum + $data2_sum values -->
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a function like this:

```
function printRow($arr){
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach($arr as $v){
           echo "<td>",$v,"</td>";
      }
      echo "<td>", array_sum($arr), "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

To Use

```
echo '<table>';
printRow($data1);
printRow($data2);
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks Orangepill! That works great for getting the table going. For the second part: is there a way to sum values with the same name from different arrays (see last table row)?

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution: http://ardamis.com/2009/10/php-function-sum-values-associative-arrays/